# Executable not runing pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable, linux-mint

My computer is runing Linux mint 20 with python 3.8

Created an executable file with PyInstaller with the following comand being in the correct PATH folder:

```
`python3 -m PyInstaller [filename.py] `
```

I had to use that command because when i tried:

```
`pyinstaller [filename.py]`
```

Got an error message stating order not found.

However it does work, it creates the excecutable but once it is created i double click it or try to open it and doesn't run.

When i run the python file with the terminal it works perfect.

I need to know what to doto get it working.

Thanks